# Shortcode not working on proper place in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have written a function and add the shortcode but when I try to use that shortcode in the center of worpdress page editor then they automatically goes top of the page and not work on right place. here is my code in function.php

```
function get_review() {  ?>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="banner-fade">
        <ul class="bjqs">
            <?php query_posts('cat=5&showposts=5&order=DESC'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="Call-to-action">
                        <div class="inside clearfix">
                            <h4>What our clients say...</h4>
                            <h5 style="width: 645px; text-align: justify;">
                                <?php   the_content(); ?>
                            </h5>
                            <a href="http://www.360creditconsulting.com/products-page/" class="call_to_action  call_to_action_contact">
                                <span>Get Started Now</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    <?php 
}
add_shortcode('get_review', 'get_review');
```

and I using the in page like :
Some content...
[get_review]

after that they auomatically shown like that
o/p of shortcode
Some content...

here is the url on which I am checking
http://www.360creditconsulting.com/test-page/

Any help will be appreciate. I am totally stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for seeing this post. I have resolved the issue with the help of ob_start() in starting of function and return ob_get_clean(); at the end of function.

Comment: I think shortcodes are meant to *return* the new value.

Comment: Shortcode functions should return the modified data. Set all of the content you are generating to a variable, and then perform return $variable at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines at the end of the script.

```
$output_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output_string;
```